# Scala Bash test scripts

Tags: bash, scala

I'm trying to write a simple batch script to test my Scala program. The script should be something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
scala ./build/classes/MyClass "../../res/some_file.txt"
```

This returns:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot figure out how to run target: ./build/classes/MyClass
```

If I'm in the classes directory running:

```
#!/bin/bash
scala MyClass "../../res/some_file.txt"
```

works as expected.

What am I doing wrong here?

-Lee

Comment: did you try replacing `./build` with `\`pwd\`/build`?

Comment: Not sure I follow what you mean by ``pwd``/build.

Comment: `scala \`pwd\`/build/classes/MyClass "../../res/some_file.txt"`

Comment: Yeah, I tried that.. no luck.

Comment: try: `scala -classpath \`pwd\`/build/classes "../../res/some_file.txt"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot pass the file name of a class -- you have to pass the class *name*, and it has to be in the classpath. So, instead, try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
scala -cp ./build/classes MyClass "../../res/some_file.txt"
```